# Bind click event function to a dynamically-created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating elements using an Ajax request. I want to bind a function to each element to run in its click event. How can I do this? Here is my code where I generate the elements.

```
ajaxCall("/getItems","POST",data,function(result){
  var element = $('.item').first();
  $('#item-list-section').empty();
  for(var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++){
    var clone = element.clone();
    clone.attr("id", result.items[i].itemId);
    clone.find('.item-price').html("<h4>25</h4>");
    if(result.items[i].itemName.length > 20){
      clone.find('.item-name').css('overflow','hidden');
      clone.attr('title', result.items[i].itemName )
    }
    clone.find('.item-name').html("<h4>"+ result.items[i].itemName + "</h4>");
    //clone.mousedown(onItemClick(clone));
    clone.draggable({
      revert : false,
      zIndex: 1,
      containment: "window",
      opacity: 0.5,
      cursor: "move",
      helper: function() { return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').show(); }
    });
    $('#item-list-section').append(clone);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Need to use event delegation** Which attaches the events to the elements using the concept of event bubbling...

```
$(staticContainer).on("click", element , function(event){
  // Code here
});
```

`staticContainer`   -- The element which is always present in the DOM.  The closer it is to the dynamically created elements the better.

`element` - Dynamically  created entity to which you want to attach the event

Answer (score 0):

```
$(clone).on("click", function(event){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Check this to find out if it alerts the id.

Answer (score 0):

In each loop of elements

```
$(clone).each(function(index, value) { 
$(value).on("click", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(clone).bind("click",function(event){
// your code
});
```

Please try this.

Comment: `on` is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click",value, function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using event delegation with `.on()` method:

```
$('#item-list-section').on('click', '.item', function () {
    // do something
});
```

Another solution is clone your element with events, just pass `true` to your `.clone()` method:

```
var clone = element.clone(true);
```

- Note that this will work if your `var element = $('.item').first();` is static on the page.

---

References:

- [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation